# The steps to develop a qgisPlugin in c++

Tags: qgis

What is the complete step of making a qgis plugin with c++, I am a newbie, just started to do this, I don't know anything. Can anyone tell me? The more detailed, the better. thank you.

You want to implement a plug-in that can read point coordinates from a file and display them on the canvas

Answer (score 1):

An overview of the steps referencing this [documentation](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/development.html) is as follows:

1. Install required software
2. Find our QGIS user profile directory
3. Use Plugin Builder to generate the plugin template
4. Create the user interface in QT Designer
5. Edit the plugin template to include our Python script
6. Test the functional plugin

For your next question, are you referring to the [Coordinate Capture Plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_coordinate_capture.html)? I'm attaching the documentation as well for your reference